# The proper type library could not be found in the system registry (VS2012 RC)

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I installed the 2012 RC on may 31, everything worked fine until today when I tried to install the TFS Power Tools Beta for TFS 11. Now every time I open VS2012 RC I'm greeted with this message:

"The proper type library could not be found in the system registry.
An Attempt to repair this condition failed because you do not have the permissions to write to the system registry or because the type library could not be loaded."
...

Every time I run VS2012 as a non admin user I get the warning. I uninstalled the Power Tools, repaired VS2012 and nothing.

I launched Process Monitor and found this:

```
devenv.exe   RegOpenKey     HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{65074F7F-63C0-304E-AF0A-D51741CB4A8D}\TypeLib            ACCESS DENIED
devenv.exe   RegOpenKey     HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{65074F7F-63C0-304E-AF0A-D51741CB4A8D}\TypeLib            ACCESS DENIED
devenv.exe   RegOpenKey     HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface                                                           ACCESS DENIED
devenv.exe   RegOpenKey     HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{D0EEAA62-3D30-3EE2-B896-A2F34DDA47D8}                    ACCESS DENIED
devenv.exe   RegOpenKey     HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{D0EEAA62-3D30-3EE2-B896-A2F34DDA47D8}                    ACCESS DENIED
devenv.exe   RegOpenKey     HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{D0EEAA62-3D30-3EE2-B896-A2F34DDA47D8}\ProxyStubClsid32   ACCESS DENIED
devenv.exe   RegOpenKey     HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{D0EEAA62-3D30-3EE2-B896-A2F34DDA47D8}\ProxyStubClsid32   ACCESS DENIED
devenv.exe   RegOpenKey     HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{D0EEAA62-3D30-3EE2-B896-A2F34DDA47D8}\TypeLib            ACCESS DENIED
devenv.exe   RegOpenKey     HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{D0EEAA62-3D30-3EE2-B896-A2F34DDA47D8}\TypeLib            ACCESS DENIED
devenv.exe   RegOpenKey     HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{D0EEAA62-3D30-3EE2-B896-A2F34DDA47D8}\TypeLib            ACCESS DENIED
devenv.exe   RegOpenKey     HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{D0EEAA62-3D30-3EE2-B896-A2F34DDA47D8}\TypeLib            ACCESS DENIED
devenv.exe   RegOpenKey     HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface                                                           ACCESS DENIED
devenv.exe   RegCreateKey   HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface                                                           ACCESS DENIED
devenv.exe   RegCreateKey   HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface                                                           ACCESS DENIED
```

But I'm stuck, I don't know how to fix this permanently, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to manually give "Full Control" permission to my user in the registry.

Right click HKEY_CURRENT_USER, click permissions... and add your user with the "Full Control" option selected.

Comment: It worked for me too (for VS2017, but had the same problem). Strange though, why I didn't have permission in my very own Local User Registry-Key!

Comment: Can someone explain on 'How to give full permissions in registry'?

Comment: @Aki Done, expanded the description