# SQL Server Management studio won't start - Type library could not be found

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I am running SQL Server Management Studio Developer Edition 2012, and the program would not start this morning. I have tried everything online, but to no avail. When I (attempt to) start the application, i am greeted with a message:

"The proper type library could not be found in the system registry

An attempt to repair this condition failed because you do not have the permissions to write tot he system registry or because thetype library could not be loaded"

If i click "ok" on this message, it is followed by an "THe application cannot start" error.

I am running as an administrator, and have tried repairing SQL Server 2012, as well as uninstalling and reinstalling it, but this error message persists. I have also tried right clicking and running as administrator, but I just get an "application cannot start" message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between these two related questions, it appears to be mostly a permissions issue:

- [The proper type library could not be found in the system registry (VS2012 RC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939877/the-proper-type-library-could-not-be-found-in-the-system-registry-vs2012-rc)
- [the proper type library could not be found in the system registry sql 2008 R2 Management Studio Error](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c8f4c820-97e4-40e9-b756-6bcba55ce0c0/the-proper-type-library-could-not-be-found-in-the-system-registry-sql-2008-r2-management-studio?forum=sqltools)

  > Change the ownership in the parent folder in registry. Give full control to local admin.
- http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS-SQL-Server/Q_24212652.html

  > Did you install SQL Server when logged in under the current user credentials?
  >
  > If not, try logging in with the credentials used when installing SQL Server 2005 and if necessary, use the repair option from add/remove programs in control panel..

Comment: Thank you! I was using procmon but the first link helped me much more than the other sql-related links i was looking at! You're awesome!

Comment: @downeysyndrome You are welcome. What exactly did you change? Since the various answers are a bit unspecific it would be nice to document something with more details.

Comment: Sorry about that, I went into ProcMon and found every key that was returning an "access denied" permissions error when starting ssms.exe, and then went into the registry and added my user profile to the permissions list.

Comment: @downeysyndrome Awesome! Thank you very much for posting those details :)