# The proper type library could not be found in the system registry SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio error

Tags: sql-server

I get this error in Management Studio. I don't know what the reason is. I tried repairing SQL Server, but still the issue is not resolved. I read a lot of articles about this, but I don't know how to do this with registry keys.

How to solve permissions issue?

[image]

Comment: Why not to install the new management studio?

Comment: i read somewhere that it will not resolved your issue if you reinstall your SQL Server. i am saving this solution for last resort.I don't know yet if this is going to work.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323963/sql-server-management-studio-wont-start-type-library-could-not-be-found

Comment: yes it is but the reason i did this post because i don't get it. I don't know how to do step by step. i want the step by step procedure to solve this issue.

Comment: i don't know how to do this "Change the ownership in the parent folder in registry. Give full control to local admin" help ??

Comment: anyone tell me in detail how to change ownership in parent folder ???

Answer (score 0):

As James suggested, it's time to use a later version of SQL Server Management Studio.

If you can run the latest (version 18.4), that would be good. It still has support for SQL Server 2008.

However, it has more recent dependencies. If you look at the list of dependencies, you might decide that an earlier version would be better on the older system. SSMS 18.4 was based on a more recent Visual Studio shell. SSMS v17.9.1 is also available for download still, works fine with SQL Server 2008, and uses the older shell, so you might have less friction when trying to install it.

Comment: so do you think i should install SQL latest version ?? tell me their won't be a same issue after installing a new version of SQL ?? i don't want a same Registry permissions error !!

Comment: Not the latest SQL version, just an update to SSMS. They are separate now. SSMS versions are now disconnected from SQL Server versions. Current SSMS versions work back to SQL Server 2008. v18.4 supports up to 2019 properly. v17.9.1 supports up to 2017.

Comment: got it thanks.Well what i did i just install the latest SQL 2018 version and migrate all the databases to new SQL and its working fine. Thanks guys